# Taylor series for exponential function.

Tags: real-analysis, definition

The Taylor series for $e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$. Then as $e^0 = 1$, if one evaluates the Taylor series at $x=0$ we find that $e^0 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{0^i}{i!} = \frac{0^0}{0!} + \frac{0^1}{1!} + \frac{0^2}{2!} + \ldots = 1$. So we are taking $0^0 = 1$?

Given we define $x^0 = 1, \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0^y = 0, \ \forall y>0 $ what is the justification for giving precedence to the former rule when evaluating the sum?

Comment: dont't you need the maclaurin series for $e^x$ agree with the value $e^0 = 1$ at $x = 0?$

Comment: The first term in the series is $ \ f(0) \ = \ e^0 \ $ , and has the associated power of $ \ x \ , \ x^0 \ = \ 1 \ $ . So the limit of the numerator as $ \ x \ \rightarrow \ 0 \ $ is $ \ 1 \ $ . A separate issue is the $ \ 0! \ $ , which is taken as equal to 1 by its connection to the gamma function.

Comment: indeed...I have seen reputable math sources declare that $0^0 = 1$, while more of them say it is indeterminate.  Certainly, in this context we can say  $\lim_\limits{x\to0} x^0 = 1.$

Comment: $0! = 1$ is by definition so I am OK with this. However how does $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^0 = 1$ justify that $0^0 = 1$? Are you inferring a continuity argument, using the continuity of $x$? In the same vein could one not take a limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 0^x = 0$ by continuity of the constant "zero function"?

Comment: Not in this case, because the first term in the Maclaurin series is $ \ \frac{f(0)}{0!} \ \cdot \ x^0 \ $ ; the zero function is not being used here.

Answer (score 1):

a) As you noticed $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right)\; \to \;\left( {0,0} \right)} x^{\,y} $ is indefinite, as it depends on the path followed to approach the origin
b) For fixed $y$, as in Taylor expansion,  a "reason" for defining $x^{\,0}  = 1\quad \left| {\;\forall x} \right.$ is (to my opinion) that we want to preserve the binomial theorem
$$
1 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\; \to \;0} \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,y}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( \matrix{
  y \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} } 
$$