# Books or online courses about defining $0^0=0$

Tags: analysis

In all my classes $0^0$ has been defined as $1$. Will defining it as $0$ somehow lead to a contradiction? If it doesn't, will we be able to develop the same theory with this definition?

This is probably a question that is asked a lot but I couldn't find any satisfactory answers so pointing me at an insightful source (like a book or an online course) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean $\lim x^x = 1$

Comment: @Nameless I wouldn't suppose that is what the OP means.

Comment: This question I asked in the past about defining $0^0 = 1$ for Taylor series may be of interest, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773090/taylor-series-for-exponential-function.

Comment: I don't think you "define" $0^0$. You think of it in terms of limits: As $x\rightarrow0$: $\lim 0^x=0$, $\lim x^0=1$ and $\lim x^x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Defining $0^0 = 1$ is usually unproblematic in a setting where exponents in some natural way is limited to being an integer (such as in combinatorics, or when working with power series or polynomials). However, if both the exponent and the base are continuous (rational, real or complex, for instance), then $0^0$ is usually left undefined because there is no value it can be given that plays nicely with continuity.

Defining $0^0 = 0$ is probably a good choice if you're in a situation where the exponents are continuous, but the base is limited to integers. I can't think of such a field right now, but I won't say there aren't any.

Comment: But if you sometimes define it as 0 and sometimes as 1, doesn't that go wrong at some point or do you just not use the theory of the other case?